# The debugger was unable to find the registration for the target application

Tags: microsoft-metro

I am testing my Windows 8 app by logging in as the guest account. I want to see how it works installing with limited permissions.

It seems I cannot debug any apps. Here are the steps:

1. Login as the Windows 8 Guest Account
2. Open Visual Studio.
3. Create a new Windows Store app, using the grid template
4. Click the play button to deploy to the simulator or the local machine.

Upon deployment, I receive this error:

Unable to debug Windows Store app App1/App1/bin/Debug/App1.exe

The debugger was unable to find the registration for the target application. If the problem persists, try uninstalling and then reinstalling the application.

Am I unable to deploy apps without being an administrator? If not, is there a way around this problem?

Comment: I too have same issue, but I am running visual studio as administrator. did you finally found the answer?

Comment: This can happen if you are actively debugging an app in an emulator, then try to start another debug deploy in another instance of visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to try to debug installing an app as a guest.  Guest accounts are not allowed to install apps.  [There is a short forum post regarding accounts here.](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/5518-user-account-type-change-windows-8-a.html)

If you are wanting to see how the app performs for a guest after it has already been installed, you can run the app from the desktop tile, but I don't know how to run the debugger on it, or even if you can.